# Invert tuples in a list of tuples

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have an array `[(126,150),(124,154),(123,145),(123,149)]`(just a sample of the numbers, the array is too large to show all of them) which I have then used `imshow` to plot the results onto a matrix. What I want is to find the inverse of the array so `[(150,126),(154,124),(145,123),(149,123)]` and then do another `imshow`.

How can I inverse the array so it achieves what I want to do?

Comment: Your question has the `numpy` tag.  Is your array stored as a numpy array?  Also, exactly how are you plotting this with `imshow`?  Could you show the code you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array = [(126,150),(124,154),(123,145),(123,149)]
inversed = [(item[1],item[0]) for item in array]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> arr = [(126,150),(124,154),(123,145),(123,149)]
>>> reverseArr = [x[::-1] for x in arr]
>>> reverseArr
[(150, 126), (154, 124), (145, 123), (149, 123)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind iterators:

```
a = [(126,150),(124,154),(123,145),(123,149)]

inverse = map(reversed, a)
```

Or here are a few options if you want tuples:

```
inverse = map(tuple, map(reversed, a))

inverse = map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), a)

inverse = zip(*reversed(zip(*a)))
```

From a couple of quick tests I found that list comprehensions are the most efficient method for short lists and the zip method is most efficient for longer lists.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: "If you don't mind iterables"? Or do I have my concepts wrong?

Comment: @Chris Wesseling Tuples are actually an iterable as well. An iterable is basically anything that can be used in a `for _ in` loop. An iterator, however, is a specific type of iterable that has a `next()` method. Iterators are lazy and to save memory each value can only be retrieved once (when `next()` is called).